# Defining mutually recursive zod schemas

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, referenceerror, zod

I am new to TypeScript and I am getting an error in the following code:

```
import { z } from "zod";

export const SpatialEntity = z.object({
  dimension_units: z.string().optional(),
  placement: SpatialPlacement
});

export const SpatialPlacement = SpatialPlacementCommon.extend({
  source: z.string().or(SpatialEntity).optional(),
  target: z.string().or(SpatialEntity)
});
```

The error is straight forward... because the variables are interdependent.

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'SpatialPlacement' before initialization
```

If I interchange the above variables i.e. If I write `SpatialPlacement` first then `SpatialEntity` then too the error is same.

Any idea how to resolve this?? Any lead would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The issue on the tin is that you are attempting to reference a value before it's definition. The core of the issue is that this schema is mutually recursive so on some level you will need [`z.lazy`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#recursive-types).

I tried to simplify the problem slightly. One issue with recursive types in zod is that you typically need to specify the types explicitly because zod cannot infer what the types should be.

```js
import { z } from "zod";

interface ISpacialEntity {
  dimension_units?: string;
  placement: ISpacialPlacement;
}

interface ISpacialPlacement {
  source?: string | ISpacialEntity;
  target: string | ISpacialEntity;
}
let SpatialEntity: z.ZodType<ISpacialEntity>;
export const SpatialPlacement: z.ZodType<ISpacialPlacement> = z.object({
  source: z.lazy(() => z.string().or(SpatialEntity).optional()),
  target: z.lazy(() => z.string().or(SpatialEntity))
});

SpatialEntity = z.object({
  dimension_units: z.string().optional(),
  placement: SpatialPlacement
});
```

The two things this is doing is:

1. It makes `SpatialEntity` available to `SpatialPlacement` by defining the value as a `let`. This lets us defer implementing the schema for this entity but makes the name part of the scope for `SpatialPlacement`.
2. The `SpatialPlacement` schema uses `z.lazy` to defer resolving the schema for `SpatialEntity`. If it tried to use the value of `SpatialEntity` without `z.lazy` then the value would still be `undefined` and things would not work as expected. (Try removing `z.lazy`; typescript will complain)

Comment: z.lazy() solved it for me. I was referencing a schema within a `BaseSchema.merge(z.object({ x: OtherSchema))` on another schema. I used `z.lazy()` on `OtherSchema` to solve it. (`BaseSchema.merge(z.object({ x: z.lazy(OtherSchema)))`