How can I use a Zod schema as a property of other schema?
I'm having the following issues with some schemas on Zod, when I try to use a schema as a field of other schema I got the following error
Implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.ts(7022)
There are my two schemas
import { z } from 'zod';
import { CurrencySchema, ManagerPaymentSchema } from '.';


export const PayPalManagerSchema = z.object({
    id: z.number().int(),
    name: z.string(),
    currency: CurrencySchema,
    paypal_link: z.string(),
    payments: z.array(ManagerPaymentSchema)
});

import { z } from 'zod';
import { PayPalManagerSchema } from '.';

export const CurrencySchema = z.object({
    idCurrency: z.number().int(),
    nameCurrency: z.string(),
    symbolCurrency: z.string(),
    codeCurrency: z.string().default('GBP'),
    paypalManagers: z.array(PayPalManagerSchema)
});

I tried making recursive types and union but it doesn't work

z.lazy might work, see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76069429/defining-mutually-recursive-zod-schemas

I solved it using zod-prisma-types, thank you!
